# Tight bound for T(n) = T(n/2) + T($\sqrt{n}$) + n

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation

I have seen examples of how to find the solve the recurrence for T(n) = T($\sqrt{n}$) + n, but how do we go about if there is another T(n/2) in there?

So I tried to unfold the recurrence out and this was what I got:

T(n) = T(n/2) + T($\sqrt{n}$) + n

= T(n/4) + T($\sqrt{n/2}$) + T($\sqrt{n}$/2) + T($\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}$) + n/2 + $\sqrt{n}$ + n

But I can't seem to find any discernable patterns here, and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to continue expanding?

I also tried substituting n = 2<sup>k</sup>, and then using S(k) = T(2<sup>k</sup>) as I've seen in T(n) = T($\sqrt{n}$) problems, but this leads to:

T(2<sup>k</sup>) = T(2<sup>k</sup>/2) + T(2<sup>k/2</sup>) + 2<sup>k</sup>

S(k) = ???

I'm quite lost as to how to continue from here! Appreciate the help as I'm quite new to this!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to prove that $T(n) \leqslant 3An$ for a certain constant $A$.

If you want to be rigorous, I think that $A = \max\{1,\max\limits_{1\leqslant n \leqslant 36}\left\{\frac{T(n)}{3n}\right\}\}$ should suffice, but that may not help you to understand the upper bound.

Comment: I assume this is via the substitution method? Where we assume T(n) = O(n) and we prove the above via induction? To add on to this, I understand that the substitution gives an upper bound big O, but does this also enable us to show a tighter bound like θ?

Comment: Yes that's it. The lower bound in $\Omega(n)$ is given because there is a $n$ in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

The related recurrence $S(n) = S(n/2) + n$ has the solution $S(n) \approx 2n$ (depending on the initial conditions and on the interpretation of $n/2$), and this suggests considering $R(n) = T(n) - 2n$, which satisfies the recurrence
$$
R(n) = T(n) - 2n = T(n/2) + T(\sqrt{n}) - n = R(n/2) + R(\sqrt{n}) + 2\sqrt{n}.
$$
The master theorem (which doesn't quite apply here!) suggests that $R(n) = \tilde{O}(\sqrt{n})$, and so that $T(n) = 2n + \tilde{O}(\sqrt{n})$, where $\tilde{O}$ is hiding logarithmic factors.

Informally, since $T(n)$ is of order $n$, we expect $T(\sqrt{n})$ to be of order $\sqrt{n}$, and so to have little effect on the asymptotics. This can be proved formally by considering the recurrence $R(n)$ above.

Comment: You can iterate this method to get more precise bounds: geometric series (ignoring the $R(\sqrt n)$ term for now) suggests $R(n)\sim2\sqrt n/(1-\sqrt{1/2})=(4+\sqrt8)\sqrt n$. Putting $R'(n)=R(n)-(4+\sqrt8)\sqrt n$, you get the recurrence $R'(n)=R'(n/2)+R'(\sqrt n)+(4+\sqrt8)\sqrt[4]n$, whose solution is $R'(n)=O(\sqrt[4]n)$. Thus, $T(n)=2n+(4+\sqrt8)\sqrt n+O(\sqrt[4]n)$. Now you can do the same thing with $R'$ if you wish to get even more precise bounds, etc.